How do I test a file field in functional tests
Does anyone have any example or reference to test file field in functional tests?
I am trying to test a file upload field in Taxonomy Entity.
My Field Definition is what in the attached image below.


I tried the below combinations but none worked.
   $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

   $page->attachFileToField('files[svg]', \Drupal::root() . '/core/misc/feed.svg');
   $page->attachFileToField('edit-upload-upload', \Drupal::root() . '/core/misc/feed.svg');
   $page->attachFileToField('Channel Logo', \Drupal::root() . '/core/misc/feed.svg');
   $page->attachFileToField('files[field_channel_logo]', \Drupal::root() . '/core/misc/feed.svg');

   $page->fillField('Choose File', 'public://test-logo.svg');

   $page->pressButton('Save');


After multiple trail and errors the following code worked.
$page->attachFileToField('files[field_original_channel_logo_0]', $file_path);
$page->attachFileToField('files[field_channel_logo_0]', $file_path1); 
$page->fillField('files[field_channel_logo_0]', $file_path2);

